# Blank page after creating war from PlayFramework with play2-war-plugin

Tags: tomcat7, web-deployment, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to deploy a HelloWorld application created with PlayFramework 2.2.2 using play2-war-plugin 1.2-beta4 on Tomcat7 (I've also tried Play 2.1.4 with play2-war-plugin 1.1.1 with same effect). I've followed the instructions on PlayFramework page to create an application and then the steps on [play2-war-plugin's site](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin) for packaging. The aplication runs fine locally with `play run` on port 9000. But after packaging and deploying, I only see a blank page in my browser.

The steps I followed:

Modified APP_HOME/project/Build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._
import com.github.play2war.plugin._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "HelloPlay"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
  .settings(Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings: _*).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here  
Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "3.0"
  ).settings(
Play2WarKeys.targetName := Some("ROOT")
  )

}
```

Modified plugins.sbt

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.2-beta4")
```

Executed `play clean`, `play dependencies`, `play war`. I obtained a war file which I then renamed to ROOT.war and deployed in WEBAPP under Tomcat7. After browsing to the relevant URL all I can see is a blank page (but no error). When I intentionally insert an incorrect URL, I'm getting a Play-like error page. I can also see, the obtained war-file doesn't include any HTML pages. May this be the cause?

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Check your tomcat logs for finding some extra information about the deploy process of your war.

Comment: If you are using LESS may be some error on LESS compilation.